# Is it harmful to use developer/stop-bath/fixer/wet-agent from different manufacturers

Tags: film, developing, fixer, developer, stop-bath

I am currently using  Adofix (fixer), 
Adostop Eco (Stop-bath) and Ilfotol (wetting-agent).

I plan to use it with Kodak D76 as developer. I wonder if it's harmful
because they come from 3 different manufacturers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I highly suggest you check out this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Darkroom-Cookbook-Alternative-Process-Photography/dp/1138959189/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=7X28P62RGESTJJRKT4MD](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1138959189)

The history of film development is a long, experimental one. Even today, people continue to experiment, even using coffee to develop the film (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caffenol).

The point of each chemical is the step it is made for. Developers develop film. Stop bath halts development. Fixer removes all developing residues and undeveloped silver and "fixes" the image in place. Permawash removes the fix. Washing for a long while removes both of those last two. Wetting agents help to get clean drying.

The point is, there's nothing about any of these chemical steps that is manufacturer dependent. The chemicals themselves are agnostic - they don't care who makes them.

So, you are perfectly in the clear to use a developer from Kodak, home-made stop bath, fixer from Ilford, perm-wash from Heico, and wetting agent from Kodak again. No harm will befall you from jealous chemicals, because chemicals cannot be jealous.

Comment: In general, all you write is correct, but there are some exotic exceptions. For example when using pyrogallol developers, it is usually recommended to use no acidic stop bath (only washing in plain water) and an alkaline or neutral fix. A pyrogallol developer creates a desirable coloured stain in the film emulsion and this stain is weakened or washed out completely by acidic stop baths or regular fixers.

Comment: @jarnbjo you're very right. I'll update this with some exceptions...should make it more long-lived as well.

Comment: To be a bit more specific on the exceptions: The chemistry is _Process_ specific, not _supplier_ specific. You can substitute suitable chemicals for a given stage of a process with a different like-chemical from another supplier. Swapping Kodak D76 for Ilford's ID-11 for the same results is one of the most 'direct swaps' - switching from Ilford's indicator stop bath for white vinegar from your kitchen is less 'direct' [as they're different acids] but achieve the same effect of using a mild acid to neutralize a basic developer. Mechanics of the process are important, not the supplier's label.